# Screen went blank after disabling XHCI Pre-Boot Mode in the BIOS

Tags: windows-7, bios

I have an Asus a55v laptop running Windows 7. I tried to open the BIOS and ended up disabling the XHCI Pre-Boot Mode. After that I saved the changes and my screen just went blank. Is it possible to undo this change in the BIOS settings or repair it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the CMOS battery from your laptop for five minutes and reinsert it. The CMOS battery is the same size and shape as a medium to large size silver colored coin. This will reset all the BIOS settings back to their factory defaults and restore the screen back to working normally.

[image]
<sup>**ASUS A55V laptop's CMOS battery**</sup>

If that doesn't work unhook the laptop's graphics card and try hooking the video cable into your TV. Undo the disabling the XHCI Pre-Boot Mode. Power the computer off, hook the graphics card back up, and switch back and connect the video cable to it. Also plug the other end of the video cable back into the laptop's screen.

Comment: Hmm, tried but it still blank.

Comment: Is it possible to unhook the graphic card?

Comment: Please don't try anything that looks like you aren't able to do it. If you get stuck it would be a good idea to take the laptop to a computer repair shop and let an expert try to fix it. If there's a quick fix for your problem you won't pay much for the time and you get the knowledge and experience of an expert for free.